# One common topic that has been discussed with increasing regularity

Tags: style, redundancy

In the following passage, is "One common topic that has been discussed with increasing regularity" considered good style? Would it be advisable to rewrite it as "One increasingly common topic"? Also, is "running and managing a household" wordy? Would it be better to remove either "running" or "managing"?

> The #MeToo movement that took center stage in 2017 brought with it conversations that went beyond rape and sexual assault. **One common topic that has been discussed with increasing regularity** is the extra effort that women put into **running and managing** a household. More often than not, this discussion will include the term emotional labor. However, the way this trending term is used is incorrect.

Comment: *Increasing regularity* does not mean the same thing as *increasingly common*. You can change the wording, but the meaning will also change.

Comment: Is there an increasingly common topic that is not discussed with increasing regularity?

Comment: As a made up example, let's say that  7 out of 10 people eat ice cream for dessert, while 3 out of 10 eat cookies. That means ice cream is more *common* than cookies. Let's say that people eat dessert only once a month. Now, let's say that people suddenly start eating  dessert twice a week—but the ratio of ice cream to cookies remains the same. Eating ice cream now becomes far more *regular*, but ice cream is still no more *common* than it was before: it remains at 7 out of 10 people. The two words mean completely different things.

Comment: For dessert, the difference is clear, but for topics, it is not so.